# Nim how to check if environment is in production?

Tags: nim-lang

Is there any convention for flagging a production env in Nim?
Like `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` in JavaScript for instance.
Or should I use pragmas like

```
when defined(release):
```

Comment: That depends on what you want. If you want to have different binaries for production, staging and local systems (all compiled from the same codebase but with different flags), it makes sense to use `when defined(compilerflag)`-syntax.
If you want to deploy the same binary everywhere and have it behave differently based on the environment,  then you should prefer checking environment variables at runtime with "if" blocks
As for how to read in environmental variables, check out https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getEnv%2Cstring%2Cstring
I don't know of a convention towards one or the other.

Comment: I got the difference between env vars and compiler symbols. I thought the community had some sort of convention like a `NIM_ENV` env var or some specific pragmas . Thanks! Ill go with that `NIM_ENV`!

Comment: I think its mostly a "What does your environment need" kind of thing. Nim is cool with both, but depending on what systems surround you there may be a preference towards one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

The `when defined(release)` line only checks at compile time if you are building a binary for release/non release, which is a [compile time symbol](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#compiler-usage-compileminustime-symbols) you get by compiling your source code with the `-d:release` switch. As such, this is not telling you anything about the runtime environment at all, but about the compilation. You could compile both debug/release binaries and use them both in production, maybe because you have a crash and need to replace your release binary with a debug version to get a meaningful stack trace/explanation.

These compile time symbols are usually embedded through the use of an external script/build machinery, like [NimScript](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nims.html), [Nimble](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble), [nake](https://github.com/fowlmouth/nake), or just a simple `.bat/.sh` file.

A line like `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` from javascript probably comes *from somewhere*, be it a static file in your project or something else. You need to figure out what exactly defines your runtime environment in production and add the Nim code necessary to detect that difference. For instance, your Nim program could run at startup a GET JSON query against a server you own and parse a `isProduction: true` value somewhere. This server could be parametrised in a configuration file where end users *specify* the environment they are actually running (or just avoid servers and read a local configuration file).

Or if you like the compile time symbols, you could have a shell script that builds your binary N times for as many different environments you want to have through the use of [user-defined pragmas](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#userminusdefined-pragmas) (and then you need to be careful about using the appropriate binary where applicable).